# recording the values even if there is no change in the data

Tags: excel, vba

My worksheet refreshes every 3 minutes and fetches data from a website , this code is recording data after every 3 minutes even if there's no change in the values in range "o1:v1". but I want it to record only when there's a change in at least one of the cells in this range. Please help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    With Worksheets("record")
       .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Resize(, 8).Value = Worksheets("record").Range("O1:V1").Value
       .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Value = Now()
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: yes , worksheet change event doesn't read the values in the range as it contains formula

Answer (score 1):

### Record Data Change (`Worksheet_Calculate`)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    ' Ranges: Source and Previous Destination
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range
    Dim cCount As Long
    With Worksheets("record")
        Set srg = .Range("O1:V1")
        cCount = srg.Columns.Count
        Set drg = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A") _
            .End(xlUp).Row, "B").Resize(, cCount)
    End With
    
    ' Arrays
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    ' Compare
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To cCount
        If sData(1, c) <> dData(1, c) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    If c > cCount Then Exit Sub ' no change
    
    ' New Destination
    Set drg = drg.Offset(1): drg.Value = sData
    drg.Resize(, 1).Offset(, -1).Value = Now

End Sub
```